# Opening images from a directory from a list of filenames

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to be able to `open/move/rename` the images form a list of filenames from a directory with hundreds of images. Unfortunately there are no wildcards, they are all `.jpg` and the images names are not sequential.

**e.g**

```
list = ['media\\1520298987567.jpg',
        'media\\1520298997109.jpg',
        'media\\1520299004063.jpg',
        'media\\1520299010082.jpg',
        'media\\1520299015452.jpg',
        'media\\1520299020690.jpg',
        'media\\1520299026092.jpg']
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean _there are no wildcards_? Did you try module `glob`?

Comment: Try not to use list <built-in function or method> as a variable name.

Comment: Yes I tried using glob, but as you can see from the examples there are no wildcards to utilse.

Comment: There is no "example" from what you provided other than a python list. You need to clarify what you want and what have you done so far?

Comment: Have you tried Pillow or wand?

Comment: You _do_ have a wildcard pattern: `'media\\*.jpg'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[glob](https://pymotw.com/3/glob/)** package in python to get list of jpg files and **os** package to perform open/move/rename operations

```
import glob 

list_of_files = glob.glob("media/*.jpg"):

for file in list_of_files: 
    # do required operation with the help of os package
```

Comment: The list is an output from a data frame which links these images to a survey site. I realize that I can use glob to search a dif for this list of images to then utilize os?

Comment: OS package you can use to perform operating system depedant functionality. check link  https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Comment: @PrashantPuri Your coding style like someone from Javascript world trying to write a python code with camelCase as variable name, and '//' as comment...

Comment: Yeah @PrashantPuri. Please try not to use Camel casing in python. **list_of_files** better suitable in python.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, (open/ move/ rename) the image files.

```
from PIL import Image
import glob, os

path = '/path/to/move/'
list_of_files = ['testfile1.jpg', 'testfile2.jpg']
for infile in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    if filename + '.' + ext in list_of_files:
        # Open the image
        im = Image.open(image_path)
        # Rename the Image
        renamed_filename = filename + '_renamed.' + ext
        # Move the image
        im.save(path + renamed_filename, 'jpg')
```

Comment: Thanks, I realize that this is how I would move/rename the files in a directory once I can access the files with the filenames in the list. My issue is the directory has hundreds of files all with similar names that glob and all are .jpg Its the opening only the files in the list that I want to achieve. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Dont you think having a if condition would work? Let me update the answer